# Determine whether R is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether R is reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, asymmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive. If the relation fails to have a property, give an example showing why it fails. Let $$A = \{1,2,3,4\}$$ and $R$ be a relation on the set $A$ defined by: $$R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1),(1,4),(3,2),(3,1),(3,4),(4,2),(4,1)\}$$

In order to solve this I drew a digraph and came up with the following answer. But I'm concerned because I got NOT on each of these. Have I done something wrong?

NOT reflexive because 4 does not have a loop.

NOT irreflexive because 1, 2, and 3 have loops.

NOT symmetric because pairs don't connect in both directions.

NOT asymmetric because some pairs connect in both directions.

NOT antisymmetric because some pairs connect in both directions.

NOT transitive because a to b and b to c then a to c does not occur.

Comment: Looks fine. You would be expected to be more explicit, for instance for not transitive by pointing at a specific example of $a$, $b$, and $c$. The "geometric" approach you used is very good.

Comment: Oh, wow, I got it right? Yay! Thank you for the input!!